# What happens with Trust Blade gets on Trust level A?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

So, to unlock every circle of Affinity Chart of Blade, you need Trust level A with Blade. After this, once you finish all nodes in Affinity Chart, you can get Trust level S. However, after this, Blade can still get Trust to get Trust levels S1, S2 etc up to lvl S8 or S9, I'm not sure.

But I have question regarding this mechanics. What happens with Trust Blade is supposed to get between level A and level S? Does it simply disappear, or accumulates towards S1+ levels? E.g. if S1 requires, say, 11k of Trust, and after getting my Blade rank A with 9600 Trust, if I get Blade 2k Trust, will it instantly get S1 after getting S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will accumulate and be allocated to the S1+ ranks. You can test this by having a blade with a non-trust 5th tier unlock condition (such as adenine), feed it a lot of pouch items, then finish the chart.

Comment: Just confirmed this for myself with Pyra. Though, it seems there is some additional action required for Trust level to actually update. After I've got her last node, I've got Trust level S, and only after some time I've noticed she has Trust level S7.

Comment: I think you just have to update trust once more after that, such as with a pouch item or combat.

Answer (score 0):

Trust will continue to build up until 59,600 Trust, at which point your blade will have rank S+ trust. Blades cannot have a trust value higher than that.

Comment: That's not the point of question. I don't care about max possible Trust, I was interested if game accumulates Trust when Blade cannot gain new Trust levels.

Comment: @lentinant Well, you asked what happens when you accumulate trust while at A rank. This answer informs you on how much trust you can possibly accumulate before you can't get anymore. It's just to make the overall answer more complete.

Comment: I was asking what happens to trust I earn while I'm not qualified to get S rank (or any rank with custom requirements, e.g. any trust ranks with Rok). So question was not how much trust I can accumulate - it was if I can accumulate trust at all.